# Can I have Tshark not truncate my urls

Tags: packet

I've been using tshark recently and I've noticed that on certain urls it truncates the URL:

> Request URI [truncated]: /2577439/300x250_062810_CLICK_AND_SAVE.swf?clickTag=http%3A//ad.doubleclick.net/click%253Bh%253Dv8/39ff/f/ae/%252a/q%253B226360793%253B0-0%253B0%253B51838704%253B4307-300/250%253B37360783/37378661/1%253B%253B%257Eo

For reference the real URL is [here](http://pda-bes.amazon.com/v?i=1$AgAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAfa9Fr8LNYzA7JJ.EJI22CtU6Gkf9JGWdncCZxY1XCRrI9GgnskS4GEAasLTiDEV5J94FdNwbIqzmT9qzSnIVZDDj6L.-LzPWe8apBxYkCnlbcdH5uJSRq5lRLLFuZkND3P011yGG9TPXur0GOmqdI7w204Y0oBpBfdIbZaZlymbPIz.ELbEbr0h64x0hN-a2CPk4uHX.Gn018wLDRTZxdRoomFPytzNoyUY55PpxrZcq4hY1U1V8bfGsnmMkMGjsKr47ELjlGB6el2AoAfAl8qFO9FBbuSqRnbtG1DRfDoDke1qEmwOjoQVyUZ9z3VxBNveU2Vv4f-n-noRwJvv4UQoXORQtPSJnL1OamffhRNX8ARjMK27atvWqjIa59x4-i26dshRR6DIcmSWKc9UUhI-zoJMJx.aOeZa.OsHedsPsJ8ViyyR8IWcq.ObsnpVgf5aqd.e2WeFkSP5-8LL8clJiHzb-9UAuErAxDEDKMuyNeQalHDJspNI5lRGGO.9gH62GkLNUR9impmnIePYdt-3vbWbKFavYHSgo7z4VEozvzaJDof60XrhmZYDZvBDcPFgTN2aacPMaJAIvL6d.V.ex0m8Ceq4SfqQFzK6ht3fyHBbC6ddStvuAhjhtp5RTCgH62rwZnto0GvDcFKknnNrYAJJi9BkBBF7nSGH4YOI6zfE-KZbc38Y2--LAzVtGAm-462.0evT9AUptMeChL.l89GdoKOROFfBM0eS1UqN4hEsBUByKwSqH582QBSiMYfCKmwrQk-EdRi4ElIEpMaxG7q5D5zywWxtya5-qqFjVD5KoqJxN-CwYg9LA5fF62NRn8QZyjk1iukX2smjiMcIcN8zB6iP-jfgD-bCtTVGWN86-vm-VLdyJxCkE.Vzr9i-sYKAeqwvUGGk-CYD1rZtZETUmDVAxQJpVbACRN5MROTh2).

Is there anyway (besides using the `-w` option to have it not truncate my urls?  I don't want to use `-w` as then I have to reconstruct the tcp packets by hand.

---

Edit: I am using `-V` to produce this output and I've tried `-s0` which does not solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-T pdml` or `-T text` both look like they output the non-truncated URL, even though `-T pdml` *says* it's truncated, it doesn't actually appear to be truncated.

Better yet, if you only want a subset of the fields, look at `-e`. For example, if you only cared about the URI, try

```
sudo tshark -e http.request.uri -T fields tcp port 80
```

...which outputs *just* the URI.  You can even use `-E` to specify how those fields are formatted in the output, for example to make it easier to parse from a script.

Comment: I want the full HTTP headers, but I'm currently using the functionality of `-V` for other information. Fields only give me a subset of all HTTP headers.  Finally, -T text didn't give me the full URL, but -T pdml may have. I have to check a few urls to be sure.

Comment: I can confirm that pdml does give the full (not truncated, despite saying otherwise) uri in the field name="http.request.uri" though not in the field that shows the GET+uri.  I've rewritten my code to work with that and marking this as the answer.